# RhoMobile ad-hoc

Tags: android, rhomobile

I've created an application with the RhoStudio SDK. On the iPhone simulator it is working well. Now I would like to install it to an android tablet. Is it possible to create a binary file which then can be copied to my device and run it? Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Run this command:

```
rake device:android:debug
```

And it will generate an .APK for you.
You will need Android SDK and NDK.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to test it.

Comment: There was a very small error in your command, thank you for your answer again. I got an error, please help me if you can.

Comment: About your second error, I have no ideas about the solution. Sorry.